# Continue counting for footnotes in a sideways-table

Tags: footnotes, counters, rotating, eledmac

I'd like my sideways-table footnotes to continue the counting of the normal footnotes.
At the moment the footnotes in my sideways-table restart counting. Here's what I've got:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, tablecaptionabove]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{eledmac}

\begin{document}

Some footnotes\footnote{Test} and some more\footnote{This is a longer one}

    \begin{sidewaystable}
        \centering

        \caption{Die vier Autoren im Vergleich}
        \foottwocolX{A}
        \let\tablefootnote\footnoteA
        \let\footnote\footnoteA
        \let\footcite\footnoteA
        \vskip\abovecaptionskip
        \begin{tabular}{p{0.2cm}|p{4.5cm}|p{4.5cm}|p{4.5cm}|p{4.5cm}}
        \toprule
         & \textsc{Karl Marx} & \textsc{Max Weber} & \textsc{Ralf Dahrendorf} & \textsc{Pierre Bourdieu} \\
         \midrule
        \begin{center}\rotatebox{90}{\textit{Definition des Klassenbegriffs}}\end{center}& \footnotesize\textit{"`Die Eigentümer von bloßer Arbeitskraft, die Eigentümer von Kapital und die Grundeigentümer, deren jeweilige Einkommensquellen Arbeitslohn, Profit und Grundrente sind, also Lohnarbeiter, Kapitalisten und Grundeigentümer, bilden die drei großen Klassen der modernen, auf der kapitalistischen Produktionsweise beruhenden Gesellschaft."'}\footnote{K. Marx, Kapital III, MEW 25, 892.} \par
        \footnotesize \textit{"`Die Spaltung der Gesellschaft in eine ausbeutende und eine ausgebeutete, eine herrschende und eine unterdrückte Klasse war die notwendige Folge der früheren geringen Entwicklung der Produktion."'}\footnote{Ebd.}& \footnotesize \textit{"`Wir wollen von einer Klasse reden, wo 1. einer Mehrzahl von Menschen eine spezifische ursächliche Komponente ihrer Lebenschancen gemeinsam ist, soweit 2. diese Komponente lediglich durch ökonomische Güterbesitz- und Erwerbsinteressen und zwar 3. unter der Bedingung des (…) Markts dargestellt wird."'}\footnote{Weber 1995: 220.}  \par
        \textit{"`'Klassen' gliedern sich nach den Beziehungen zur Produktion und zum Erwerb der Güter, 'Stände' nach den Prinzipien ihres Güterkonsums in Gestalt spezifischer Arten von 'Lebensführung.'"`}\footnote{Ebd.} & \footnotesize \textit{"`Soziale Klassen sind quasi-Gruppen […] die als Träger gemeinsamer Interessen am sozialen Wandel beteiligte Kräfte darstellen."'}\footnote{Dahrendorf 1968: .} \par
        \textit{"`Soziale Klassen sind, im Gegensatz zu sozialen Schichten, nicht in sich einheitliche Gebilde, als Ganze anderen ähnlichen Einheiten über- oder untergeordnet."'}\footnote{Dahrendorf 1968: .}\par
        \textit{"`Soziale Klassen sind [...] immer entlang den Linien der sozialen Schichtung gebildet.'"}\footnote{Dahrendorf 1968: .}
        & die Frau \\
        \hline
        \begin{center}\rotatebox{90}{\textit{Entwicklung}}\end{center}& -- & \footnotesize Weiterentwicklung des Klassenbegriffes von Karl Marx, jedoch mit Erweiterungen. Weber lehnt Marx’s Determinismus ab und spricht den Individuen eigene Handlungsfähigkeiten zu, die sich auf die jeweiligen Klassenzugehörigkeiten auswirken. & \footnotesize Verankerung des Klassenbegriffes in die Moderne. Als Argument dafür dient Dahrendorf die Tatsache, dass die Ursprünge für unterschiedliche Klassen nicht aus der Welt geschaffen sind und somit die Klassengesellschaft weiterhin existiert. & den Mann \\
        \hline
        \begin{center}\rotatebox{90}{\textit{Begriffe}}\end{center}& \footnotesize Klassenkampf; Klassenbewusstsein; Diktatur des Proletariats; Historischer Materialismus; Klasse an sich, Klasse für sich; Lumpenproletariat & \footnotesize Besitzklasse vs. Erwerbsklasse;
        Klassen, Stände und Parteien; Lebenschancen; Herrschaft, Macht und soziale Ehre & \footnotesize Soziale Schicht vs. soziale Klasse; quasi-Gruppen: \begin{compactitem}\item partielle Konflikte \item sektionelle Konflikte \item parallele Konflikte (Klassenkonflikte)\end{compactitem} & das Kind \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{sidewaystable} 

    \pagebreak

\end{document}
```

Does anyone know, how I get my footnotes not to restart at 1, whenever I make a table?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\footnote` and `\footnoteA` use two different counter.That why the counting in note is not the same. You just have to let the counter for `\footnoteA` be an alias of the one for `\footnote`.

Just add

```
\makeatletter\let\c@footnoteA\c@footnote\makeatother
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought that was the problem, but couldn't think of an answer... Thanks alot, that worked great!

Comment: I was using \setcounter, but your solution is better.